# Recording "Stereo Mix" in Adobe Audition

Tags: windows-8, audio, adobe-audition

I am trying to record my Stereo Mix into Adobe Audition and I cannot get it to work. All I hear is a hiss from the Stereo Mix. When I choose *Listen to device* in the settings, all I hear is a hiss and it registers no input.

- I have enabled Stereo Mix in Adobe Audition, Windows 8, and the Audio Software that came with computer.
- I have disabled all inputs *but* the stereo mix.
- My sound card is VIA High Definition Audio
- I am running the latest drivers.

How do I solve this issue?

Comment: When you say "enabled", do you mean you've selected Stereo Mix as your input in Audition?  Are you certain it's not trying to record from some other input device?  Check the input channel settings for your track.

Comment: @paddy - I have enabled the Stereo Mix *and* selected it for the input. I have double checked my settings and all is set correctly from what I can tell.

Answer (score 0):

Use VB Cable.

I had the same issue, and could not seem to get my audio apps to record what I'm hearing in windows. This driver installs a new input/output which you can use to capture the audio playing.

https://www.vb-audio.com/Cable/

Works like a charm!

If you want to hear what you are recording in windows through your speakers, set 'Listen to this device' by right clicking on the new output channel created in your Sound > Recording window and checking 'Listen to this device', then in the drop down select your output/speakers.

Cheers!